# Spring's @Scheduled error : Only one AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor may exist within the context

Tags: spring, scheduler, spring-3, crontrigger

I am trying Spring 3's @Scheduled annotation . Here is my configuration (app.xml) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
  xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
      "
>

  <context:component-scan base-package="destiny.web"/>  
  <context:annotation-config/>
  // other beans

  <task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor" scheduler="myScheduler"/>
  <task:executor  id="myExecutor"  pool-size="5"/>
  <task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="10"/>
</beans>
```

And this is my service class :

```
@Service
public class ServiceImpl implements Service , Serializable
{
  //other injections

  @Override
  @Transactional
  public void timeConsumingJob()
  {
    try
    {
      Thread.sleep(10*1000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  @Override
  @Scheduled(cron="* * * * * ?") 
  public void secondly()
  {
    System.err.println("secondly : it is " + new Date());
  }
}
```

It works fine when testing in my eclispe + junit , when testing a timeConsumingJob method , I can see secondly() continues outputting message secondly.

But when deployed to a container (Resin/4.0.13) , it throws :

```
[11-03-26 12:10:14.834] {main} org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Only one AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor may exist within the context.
Offending resource: class path resource [app.xml]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:72)
 at org.springframework.scheduling.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java:82)
```

I searched but seldom find similar situations , I think it is the most basic setting , but don't know why it doesn't work .

Can somebody take a look at it ? Thanks a lot !

(Spring 3.0.5 , Resin 4.0.13)

------------ **updated** ---------

After I dig deeper , I found the app.xml is imported by another xml. Maybe this is the reason makes `task:annotation-driven` not working.

Well , after re-arranging some beans' location , it is solved, but I still feel puzzled. (Because it worked fine , and other.xml needs beans in app.xml )

Comment: Arr you sure you're not including `app.xml` twice, somehow? How have you configured that?

Comment: Hi , I am sure app.xml is included once. (in web.xml's context-param's contextConfigLocation )

Comment: Hi, thnx, I had same problem and got solved now. In my case also, the xml file was imported at two places and so was getting this error but then removed that import from one place and now resolved this error.

Answer (score 16):

The application context is being initialized twice but org.springframework.scheduling.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser fails registering bean ASYNC_ANNOTATION_PROCESSOR_BEAN_NAME second time.

I encountered this problem in unit tests where @ContextConfiguration("/path/to/applicationContext.xml") was accidentally on both the parent test class and child test class (with default value of inheritLocations true).

Comment: Thx for this answer, it gave me the final clue. I had included the app.xml both in my web.xml and as @ImportResource in java. Which worked before I started on the task namespace!

Comment: +1 This was definitely that problem I had in my code. It only happened in my integration testing, mostly because my integration tests, in their `@ContextConfiguration` include the applicationContext.xml, which is also included as part of the web.xml. And my task:annotation drive annotation was defined in the application context. This cause a double definition. To make things more interesting, this only failed when running with JDK 8, but ran perfectly with JDK 7. I have no clue why.

Answer (score 8):

I have faced this once after implementing our own AsyncTaskExecutor and forgetting to remove default `<task:annotation-driven/>`

Check if you have something like this, if yes remove one of the task.

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="customAsyncTaskExecutor" scheduler="taskScheduler"/>

<task:annotation-driven/>
```

Answer (score 7):

This happens when spring parses the `<task:annotation-driven/>` text twice in a config XML.

For me this was happening because both `applicationContext-root.xml` and `applicationContext-where-annotation-driven-is-specififed.xml` were imported in my `WEB.xml` in `<context-param>` section.

Leaving only `applicationContext-root.xml` in `WEB.xml` solved the issue.

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem when I copied `applicationContext.xml` and created new one called `applicationContextAdditional.xml`. I didn't try to find the reason, but both contained namespace

```
<bean ...
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    ...
    xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd" >

    ...

</bean>
```

when I removed the namespace from the second one my problem was solved. Maybe it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this was caused by switching versions, thereby in the output file location there are multiple version of jars (and therefore each jar contains a AnnotationBean):

```
2018-02-19 13:38:44,913 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Only one ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor may exist within the context.
Offending resource: URL [jar:file:/C:/.../lib/xxx-2.0.jar!/META-INF/spring/xxx.xml]
```

while I'm using 1.0 in this case. So I have to manually delete `C:/.../lib/xxx-2.0.jar` in this location, and I'm able to see xxx-1.0.jar is also in this directory. After the manual deletion, it works normally.

Answer (score 1):

I had the `<task:annotation-driven/>` defined twice in the context xml. Removing that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

That error, about

```
Only one AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor may exist within the context
```

, can appear in one more case. I do not insist, that that must help you, maybe you really have some complicated problem, described in other posts, but no one of them helped me.

What did help, was simple

```
mvn clean
```

, for the project somehow had created some duplicated files and those caused the problem. And a simple clean had... ehm... cleaned them.

That situation, for example, can happen after a merge with a branch with a higher version of the project.