# Support for multiple thread pool in same context

Tags: spring, threadpool, executorservice

In Spring @Async , If i want to have multiple executor pool with different queue capacity - I get the error "Only one AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor may exist within the context".

From the below links I observe that this is not feasible .

[Only one AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor may exist within the context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017278/only-one-asyncannotationbeanpostprocessor-may-exist-within-the-context)

[Spring's @Scheduled error : Only one AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor may exist within the context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440429/springs-scheduled-error-only-one-asyncannotationbeanpostprocessor-may-exist)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367572/how-to-configure-multiple-threadpooltaskexecutors-within-the-same-application-co

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/79086-multiple-executor-possible

Is there any alternative ( other than using spring-integration )

Below is my configuration

My configuration is like below

```
<!- Executor A -->
<task:annotation-driven executor="executor_A"/>
<task:executor id="executor_A" pool-size="100"/>

<!- Executor B -->
<task:annotation-driven executor="executor_B"/>
<task:executor id="executor_B" pool-size="100"/>
```

The above two configurations are defined in different xml context files and all are loaded in to same application context

From the source code , I am mapping to the specific executor

```
@Async("executor_A")
public void testExecutorA()
{
}



@Async("executor_B")
public void testExecutorB()
{
}
```

When I deploy , I  get the below error

2014-07-22 09:41:26.644 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader U: SC: TX: - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath*:/META-INF/domainconfig/*-domain-context.xml]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Only one AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor may exist within the context.
Offending resource: URL [jar:file:/D:/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.29/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/lib/myapp-domain-1.0.0.jar!/META-INF/domainconfig/my-domain-context.xml]

Thanks

Lives

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't explained much what your configuration looks like but it's possible to have different `ExecutorService` in the same context. Your last link to the forum actually has a comment with the reference to [the issue that implements this feature](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6847).

Just define them and *qualify* the `@Async` annotation with the service you want to use for a particular invocation, something like:

```
@Async("myExecutor")
public Future<Foo> handle() { ... }
```

When you have multiple matching candidates, you need to specify which one is going to be used if none is specified explicitly (that is define the *default* service to use). To do so, specify it either with the `<task:annotation-driven/>` element

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor"
```

or

```
@EnableAsync
@Configuration
public class AppConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {

    public Executor getAsynchExecutor() { ... }
}
```

Check [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support) for more details.

(Note that as of Spring framework 4.1, the `AsyncConfigurer` has an extra method and you should prefer extending from the `AsyncConfigurerSupport` instead).

Comment: Thanks  for the response . I have added the details to my main qs

Comment: Well, I already replied you. You can't define the `task:annotation-driven` element twice. Just register once with the main executor you want to use and when you need a different one, just define it in the annotation.

Comment: Sorry - I could not follow . If I need a different executor pool and if i define it as an annotation with @Async - what would be the pool size of that executor pool ? Will it be that of the default one I define ? Or can i define the pool size as well in the annotation ?

Comment: Thanks Stephane - I got it now .
It should be like below 

 <task:annotation-driven executor="default_executor"/>
 <task:executor id="default_executor" pool-size="100"/>
 <task:executor id="custom_executor" pool-size="10"/>

Comment: how can I have different executor with using @EnableAsync?

Comment: If I have multiple `Executor`s defined as you have in the example above, how do I get them to use the same `AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler`.  It seems like I can only define it for the default Executor in the  `AsyncConfigurer.getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler` method I override and not for the named ones.

Comment: that's not what I see in the code. The handler is used regardless of the executor. If you can share a sample that shows the problem, feel free to create an issue. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Dejell, did you get your answer? I am also looking for a solution on how to have two or more `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` beans in an application using annotations i.e `@EnableAsync`.