# How to override default AsyncConfigurer in Spring (get rid of "only one configurer may exists")

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, spring-boot

I must put my own Executor to work with Spring @Async annotation. For this, I wrote the class along the lines

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class ConnectedThreads implements AsyncConfigurer {

  @Override
  public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
    return ...
```

When I try to run the Spring Boot application with this class, the applications crashes with

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only one AsyncConfigurer may exist
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AbstractAsyncConfiguration.setConfigurers(AbstractAsyncConfiguration.java:68)
```

There is no another configurer in the project. It is a very small project, and I have full control over it. I myself suspect that the custom configurer may simply conflict with the default configurer.

Is there any possibility to say to Spring that THIS is the configurer I need and it should not look for any other?

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/a/22724565/655249

Comment: Thanks. However my app does not have XML files at all, it is fully annotation driven.